# System.Security.SecurityException C# 2.0 windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I`m tring to install my windows service on Windows 7 x64

And getting this error

```
An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the System.Diagnostics.EventLogInstaller installer.
System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.
An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the installation. This exception will be ignored and the rollback will continue. However, the machine might not fully revert to its initial state after the rollback is complete.
```

this is my `MyWindowsServiceInstaller` code:

```
var processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            var serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
            processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "My Service";
            serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Manual;
            serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "My Service";
            this.Installers.Add(processInstaller);
            this.Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
```

i have set my application name to start up project

Here is bat file

```
@ECHO OFF

REM The following directory is for .NET 2.0
set DOTNETFX2=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
set PATH=%PATH%;%DOTNETFX2%

echo Installing MyService...
echo ---------------------------------------------------
InstallUtil /i ConsoleApplication5.exe
echo ---------------------------------------------------
echo Done.
pause
```

This service is not only my computer if i will solve this problem it would be solved for any other computers?

Thanks

Comment: Are you executing the batch file with elevated privileges using an account that is member of the Administrators group?

Comment: thank you for replay i run batch file run as administrator and got this error >> exception occured while intilizing the intaallation: system.io.filenotfoundException: could not load file or assembly file://c:\windows\system32\ConsoleApplication5.exe or one of its dependencies. The System cannot find the file specified

Comment: You probably right clicked and chose Run as administrator. This basically logs in as a new user, changing the current working directory. Try opening a new CMD window, elevated as admin, then navigate to the install directory and execute the batch file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

U can try installing in this way.
Open cmd as administator and locate to .Net Framework path in your system

```
Eg: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\"
```

Then with the help of installutil.exe you can install the service.

```
Eg: C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe "Your service exe path"
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also overcome such issue by starting "Visual Studio Command Prompt" as **"Run as administrator"** option. Now install your assembly with installutil.exe command

```
x:\Windows\System32>installutil.exe YourService.exe
```

*(Where YourService.exe is the compiled exe file of your service project)*

**Directions:**
To open the command prompt, click on "All Programs" -> "Microsoft Visual Studio (20xx)" -> "Visual Studio Tools (20xx)" -> "Visual Studio Command Prompt" (where 20xx is the respective version you are using like 2008, 2010 etc.).